# Get attributes from item(tag) using SimplePie

Tags: php, rss, feed, simplepie

I'm trying to get attributes for "id" tag in feed with usage of simplepie.

This is the fragment of code from feed:

```
<updated>2012-03-12T08:26:29-07:00</updated>
<id im:id="488627" im:bundleId="dmtmobile">http://www.example.com</id>
<title>Draw Something by OMGPOP - OMGPOP</title>
```

I want to get number (488627) from **im:id** attribute contained in **id** tag

How can I get this ?

I tried `$item->get_item_tags('','im:id')` but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

If this is in an Atom 1.0 feed, you'll want to use the [Atom namespace](http://www.simplepie.org/wiki/faq/supported_xml_namespaces):

```
$data = $item->get_item_tags(SIMPLEPIE_NAMESPACE_ATOM_10,'id');
```

From there, you should then find that the attributes you want are:

```
$id = $data['attribs'][IM_NAMESPACE]['id']
$bundleID = $data['attribs'][IM_NAMESPACE]['bundleId']`
```

where `IM_NAMESPACE` is set to the `im` XML namespace (i.e. what the value of `xmlns:im` is).

Answer (score 0):

The reason SimplePie asks for a namespace is because it internally stores the node elements under the given namespace. If you don't know what your specific namespace is, use print_r to dump it:

```
print_r($item->data['child']);
```

You can also directly access the child elements if you know the namespace, or write a simple seeker function to step through each namespace and look for a matching tag.

```
$data = $item->data['child']['im']['bundleId'][0]['data'];
```

The get_item_tags() function is stupid and doesn't usually do what you want, but it's also very simple and easy to replace with your own special purpose functions. Original source is:

```
public function get_item_tags($namespace, $tag)
{
    if (isset($this->data['child'][$namespace][$tag]))
    {
        return $this->data['child'][$namespace][$tag];
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```